# How to make recorded macro work on any sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I recorded a macro to sort my excel sheet by Number (which is column A), then ID (which is column D), then the newest-oldest Date (which is column M)

I want to be able to copy this macro onto any sheet (which would have all the same columns), but it tells me "subscript out of range" because there are different names.

Here is the macro. The sheet name is "owssvr (1)", but I'd like it to be able to be for any sheet that has the same columns and such:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("owssvr (1)").ListObjects("Table_owssvr__2").Sort. _
    SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("owssvr (1)").ListObjects("Table_owssvr__2").Sort. _
    SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table_owssvr__2[Number]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues _
    , Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("owssvr (1)").ListObjects("Table_owssvr__2").Sort. _
    SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table_owssvr__2[ID]"), SortOn:= _
    xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("owssvr (1)").ListObjects("Table_owssvr__2").Sort. _
    SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table_owssvr__2[Date]"), SortOn:= _
    xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("owssvr (1)").ListObjects("Table_owssvr__2"). _
    Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

I was thinking of using something w/ a With

Comment: How many sheets are in workbook?

Comment: just one sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work on any sheet which has only a single listobject which contains the required column names:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim tName As String

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort

        tName = .Parent.Name 'list name

        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(tName & "[Number]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(tName & "[ID]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(tName & "[Date]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply

    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

*Reference your worksheet name by Index Number*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
End Sub
```

*[Referring to Sheets by Index Number [Excel 2003 VBA Language Reference]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221564(v=office.11).aspx)*

> *<sub>An index number is a sequential number assigned to a sheet, based on the position of its sheet tab (counting from the left) among sheets of the same type. The following procedure uses the Worksheets property to activate worksheet one in the active workbook.</sub>*

Comment: @Kelley replace your sheet name with 1 - Example `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("owssvr (1)")` with `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)`

Answer (score 0):

There **two** things at issue here:

1. the worksheet name
2. the Table name

Lets assume that the name of the table is the same on all sheets on which the macro is to be used.  First Activate the worksheet and then run:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.ListObjects("Table_owssvr__2").Sort. _
    SortFields.Clear
ws.ListObjects("Table_owssvr__2").Sort. _
    SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table_owssvr__2[Number]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues _
    , Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ws.ListObjects("Table_owssvr__2").Sort. _
    SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table_owssvr__2[ID]"), SortOn:= _
    xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
ws.ListObjects("Table_owssvr__2").Sort. _
    SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table_owssvr__2[Date]"), SortOn:= _
    xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ws.ListObjects("Table_owssvr__2"). _
    Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```